# pjsip 2.5.5 with IPV6 support in iOS app

Tags: ios, voip, pjsip

I am using pjsip 2.5.5 with my iOS application. While running app in only IPV6 enabled network, sip registration is not working. but if I run the same code for IPV4 enabled network, It works for sip registration. I am not getting where is the things are missing or how can we get description for exact issue? Is there any flag or any other support we need to add to use the library for the network IPV4 and IPV6? Any clue will be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK pjsip does not support dual stack IPv4/IPv6. You need to create separate transports for IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint. Can you please tell me exactly how I can create separate transport for IPV4 and IPV6? Any link or any detail Please..

Comment: pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TLS, &transportConfig, &transportId);
pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TLS6, &transportConfig, &transportId);

And then write something like transport manager that will manage connection.
I'm doing it right now. Couse have same problem with IPv6 with pjsip 2.5.5.
But it seems to be pjsip 2.5.5 is completely broken(((

Comment: I made changes as with pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TLS6, &transportConfig, &transportId); But still seems same problem . Do I need to build project again after making this changes?

Comment: Any success you got? I am still facing this problem. Even some live applications downloaded from app store is having the same issues .

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with my iOS applicatoin before. below are the my steps.

1)I recompile pjsip library to support ipv6, add " #define PJ_HAS_IPV6" to config.h. The detail info you can refer to 
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/IPv6#IPv6Supportinpjlib.

2)The ipv4 address change to domain. May be need to change some config, this is backend developers config, so I don't know the detail info.

3)Create ipv6 transport and Adding SIP Account. the detail code follw https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/IPv6#IPv6Supportinpjlib.

If all is normal, you can register now. But can't make call.

I fixed ipv6 make call refer to https://github.com/johanlantz/pj-nat64. I put the code pj-nat64() to my project and config.

Comment: For this solution , did you required to have server enabled with IPv6??

Comment: No need, client config only.

Comment: Means we client have to configure on server? Can you please elaborate? This may help me a lot.

Comment: @young I don't understand the step 3. how to create ipv6 transport and adding sip account . please explain